# Accessing specific API

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

So I am trying to access an OpenFEMA API for funding data, but I am pretty new to APIs and I am trying to access the API using Javascript. I ran into the Same-Origin Problem and started using CORS.

So my code currently looks like this:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        console.log('1');
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        console.log('2');
    } else {
        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;
        console.log('3');
    }
    return xhr;
}

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', "http://www.fema.gov/api/open/v1/PublicAssistanceFundedProjectsDetails");

alert(xhr.responseText);
```

but the alert box is empty when it comes up. I am really not sure what I am doing wrong. would love some help.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that means

Comment: you have to wait for it to be loaded.

Comment: Oh okay so the dataset is currently too big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are using only creates the request; it doesn't send it or wait for results. You would still need to set up an `onReadyStateChange` handler, then call `xhr.send()`, to see the results.

More importantly, though, the API you are accessing does not permit cross-origin requests. It cannot be accessed from off-site through Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for actually checking the API. I was starting to get the impression that the API doesn't allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: Also how would I access the API then?

Comment: You can't — at least, not from Javascript. You would need to call it from a server-side script, or in a non-web-based application.